# Validation of files based on their file extensions

Tags: java, excel, pdf, file-upload, ms-word

I get files from queues in Java. They may be of following formats.

1. docx
2. pdf
3. doc
4. xls
5. xlsx
6. txt
7. rtf

After reading their extensions, I want to validate whether they are actually files of these types.

For example, I got a file and checked that it has extension .xls. Afterwards, I want to check whether it is actually an .xls file or someone uploaded file of some other format after changing its extension.

EDIT: I'd like to check the file's MIME type by actually checking its content, not its extension. How it can be done?

Comment: Are you sure you need to do this? Can't you just pass the file to whatever process needs to use it and just handle exceptions if the file is invalid?

Comment: Also, you won't be able to validate a .txt file without specifying some arbitrary restrictions.

Comment: @Duncan...actually the file is being stored to file system. So before we store, we want to check it is valid file or not. make sense.?

Comment: Not to me, I'm afraid. I'd be more interested if a file is valid when I come to use it. In particular, any solution to this problem will scale badly, requiring changes for each newly supported file type.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is a problem you should be solving. Any solution to this problem would be brittle and based upon your current understand of what constitutes a valid file of a particular type.

For example, take a XLS file. Do you know for sure what Excel accepts when opening such a file? Can you be sure you'll keep abreast of any changes in future releases that might support a different encoding style?

Ask yourself - what's the worse that could happen if the user uploads a file of the wrong type? Perhaps you'll pass the file to the application that handles that file extension and you'll get an error? Not a problem, just pass that to the user!

Comment: I just wanted to check file's mime type by actually its content not by its extension.

Comment: @Ahmad I understand what you would like to do. I'm suggesting (for the reasons listed above) that this might not be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Without using external libraries:

You can get the file mimetype using MimetypesFileTypeMap:

```
    File f = new File(...);
    System.out.println(new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(f));
```

You can get a similar result with:
[URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromName%28java.lang.String%29)
Both these solutions, according to the documentation, look only at the extension.

A better option: [URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromStream%28java.io.InputStream%29)

```
    File f= new File(...);
    System.out.println(URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(new FileInputStream(f)));
```

This try to guess from the first bytes of the file - be warned this is only a guess - I found it works in most cases, but fails to detect some obvious types.

I recommend a combination of both.

Comment: Is this an answer? It seems you are just mapping file extensions to mime types, not validating the contents as the OP demands.

Comment: Sorry - I remember I had the same problem in the past, just copied the wrong solution from my code!

Comment: I removed the -1 after you last suggestion. But I'm still convinced this is a fool's errand :-)

Comment: `File f= new File(...);` => this (...) mean that you need enumerate extensions?