# Validate file contents based on extension

Tags: java

I want to validate file contents based on their extension. For example, a user can save a document file (.doc/.docx) as an Excel file (.xls/.xlsx). Before I get the file contents, using Java I need to validate the content type matches with that extension.

Is any one have idea about, please share your points.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want; try to give us an example of a good case and a bad case (when your validation fails)

Comment: I thought all files will be saved in same "bits" of 0 and 1 and in byte format. In short, there's no universal solution for "All"

Comment: I want file content. For that just do a validation before get records like that if it is txt file i validate whether saved in that file is txt format or other format.

Comment: From [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13250009/836214) in the question Duncan linked to above: "Any solution to this problem would be brittle and based upon your current understand of what constitutes a valid file of a particular type"

Answer (score 0):

There exists projects already to detect the details of a file. The [file](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command on linux can do this for example.

A Java project called [Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) might be useful to you, Tika will parse the file(s) specified on the command line and output the extracted text content or **metadata** to standard output.